# ruamel.yaml octal in 1.1

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I tried to run this code with PyYAML:

```
from yaml import safe_load
data = safe_load("""\
%YAML 1.2
---
x: 42
y: 0x2a
z: 0o52
""")

assert data['x'] == data['y'] == data['z']
```

and did not expect it to throw an assertion error. After I read more documentation (found via http://yaml.org/), I realized PyYAML died some time ago and never supported the octal integers from the YAML 1.2 specficiation.

With ruamel.yaml (`from ruamel.yaml import safe_load`) the above works as expected.

Just out of curiosity I tried ruamel.yaml with the old octal format ( `YAML 1.1` at the top and `z: 052`) and that works as well. I also tried the below:

```
from ruamel.yaml import safe_load
data = safe_load("""\
%YAML 1.1
---
x: 42
y: 0x2a
z: 0o52
""")
assert data['x'] == data['y'] == data['z']
```

expecting it throw an error, as `data['z']` should be a string, and not the integer 42. This doesn't throw an error, where I suppose it should.

Is my expectation wrong, or is this a bug in ruamel.yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that that is a bug in ruamel.yaml 0.14.2.

The implicit resolvers for integers for 1.1 and 1.2 both include the 0o pattern, and only the one for 1.2 should have that. The old pattern (matching `052`) is available only when version 1.1 is asked for.

This should be fixed in ruamel.yaml>=0.14.3